# Get result from an activity started in proccessCommandApdu

Tags: android, android-activity, service, nfc, hce

I am creating an Android app that communicates with a NFC Reader using HCE feature.
The scenario is, when app receives a command, the **processCommandApdu** method will be called and will start an activity. In that activity there is an EditText and a button. User can enter some text, then clicks the button and the text will be sent to the NFC Reader. 
I can start activity from the service, but what I don't understand is how I can return back the entered text to **HostApduService** to send it to the NFC Reader.

Is there any good way to do this? for example, saving the entered text in an application variable (or database) in the activity, finishing activity, then read the variable in the service and return it to the NFC Reader. Do I need some waiting techniques in the service if using this way? Or is there any better solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you want to do something with `publish and subscribe` pattern.
[EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/) is a library that can help you to post data between classes when it's ready for use.

You may also want to read about [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694) tutorial first to see if that meet your needs.